# QUERY TOMAR TOP 5 POR MES

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Miren estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente consulta.

Que por mes (enero, febrero, marzo , .etc.), se tenga el top 5 de vendedores.

```
    SELECT
        MONTH(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER) AS MONTH,
        ORDER1.ID_SELLER,
        COUNT(ORDER1.ID_ORDER) AS CANTIDAD_VENTAS,
        SUM(ORDER1.PRICE) AS TOTAL_VENTAS,
        SUM(ORDER1.AMOUNT) AS CANTIDAD_PROD_VENDIDOS
    FROM TRANSACCION_ORDER ORDER1
    WHERE (YEAR(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER)) = 2020
    GROUP BY MONTH,ORDER1.ID_SELLER
    ORDER BY MONTH,TOTAL_VENTAS DESC;
```

Si bien esto me arroja un resultado correcto, no logro dar con que solo me tome el top 5. Si lo hago con el limit me toma los 5 de todos los meses y yo necesito que por el mes de enero me tome el top 5, para febrero me tome su top 5 y asi sucesivamente.

Este es el resultado que arroja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya les agradezco la ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Puedes poner si puedes el resultado esperado por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba apoyándote en una variable:

```
SET @i=0,@mes=0;
SELECT IF(@mes!=MONTH(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER),@i:=0,0),
    IF(
      @autonomia!=MONTH(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER),
      @autonomia:=MONTH(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER),0
    ),
    @i:=@i+1 orden,
    MONTH(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER) AS MONTH,
    ORDER1.ID_SELLER,
    COUNT(ORDER1.ID_ORDER) AS CANTIDAD_VENTAS,
    SUM(ORDER1.PRICE) AS TOTAL_VENTAS,
    SUM(ORDER1.AMOUNT) AS CANTIDAD_PROD_VENDIDOS
FROM TRANSACCION_ORDER ORDER1
WHERE (YEAR(ORDER1.DATE_ORDER)) = 2020
GROUP BY MONTH,ORDER1.ID_SELLER
HAVING orden<=5
ORDER BY MONTH,TOTAL_VENTAS DESC;
```

La idea es montar un contador por cada grupo principal y que únicamente muestre aquellos cuyo contador `orden` no supere el 5.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta de verdad, nunca se me habría ocurrido algo así te has ganado mi voto amigo :)

Comment: Bueno, me falta arreglarla con un `IF(@autonomia!=autonomia,@i:=0)` pero ahora no puedo, en un rato la termino... :)

Comment: si pero demasiado bueno es ya de por si

Comment: Buenas, probe lo que me dices pero pasa lo siguiente, yo necesito que por mes tenga su top 5

Comment: Entonces añádele un ``LIMIT 5 `` y solucionado ordenandolo de forma descendentemente con ``ORDER BY columna DESC`` @Valpenr_994

Comment: No te funciona porque no está terminada, dame unos minutos que la corrijo :)

Comment: @DavidJP con lo que puse yo en el comentario de arriba valdría?

Comment: No, es precisamente lo que comenta en la pregunta: el `LIMIT 5` no sirve, por eso hay que hacer lo de la variable...

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: Ok, ya está. Ahora sí que debería funcionar como se espera

Comment: Puff pues no esta funcionando

Comment: Ok, modifica la pregunta añadiendo los `CREATE TABLE` y los `INSERT` para tratar de reproducir la consulta. Puedes hacerlo con phpmyadmin, exportar. Si la consulta que has puesto funciona, con estos cambios también debería funcionar, pero igual hay algo más...